# Deep Nested Tag IDs not found using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape NBA data from https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html, but I am running into issues where BeautifulSoup drops deeply nested tags.

I tried to use `soup.find(id='opponent-stats-per_game')` to grab the "Opponent Per Game Stats" table. However, I am getting `None` result. If I try to instead find a div that is higher up in the tree, then it clips the more deep children.

Could someone please offer me some guidance on how this works? I am fairly new to web scraping using BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference.com sites are partially dynamic. I had the same issue a long while back when trying to figure out football-reference.com

There's a couple ways to handle it. One is to use Selenium to render the page first, and then you can go in and grab the tables. Now you can still use BeautifulSoup to get it, but whenever I see `<table>` tags, my first initial try is to use pandas and `.read_html()`, as that'll do most of the work for you on the tables.

This will return a list of dataframes. It's then just a matter of finding which dataframe you want, and then possibly do a little manipulation of column names and what-not to get it the way you need.

Doing this, your opponent stats per game table was in index position 19:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
page_url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html'
driver.get(page_url)

tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
opp_per_gm_df = tables[19]

driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
print (opp_per_gm_df)
      Rk                     Team   G     MP    FG  ...  STL  BLK   TOV    PF    PTS
0    1.0        Memphis Grizzlies  77  242.3  37.2  ...  7.7  4.9  15.5  21.7  105.6
1    2.0               Miami Heat  77  240.3  38.2  ...  7.4  4.8  14.2  20.3  105.6
2    3.0          Indiana Pacers*  78  240.3  38.7  ...  7.5  5.2  15.6  20.1  104.3
3    4.0               Utah Jazz*  77  240.6  39.7  ...  8.6  4.7  13.9  22.2  106.1
4    5.0          Denver Nuggets*  77  240.6  39.6  ...  7.5  5.0  13.5  20.5  106.9
5    6.0          Detroit Pistons  77  242.3  40.0  ...  6.9  5.2  14.1  21.5  107.5
6    7.0            Orlando Magic  78  241.3  39.9  ...  6.9  4.4  13.0  18.8  106.5
7    8.0          Boston Celtics*  78  241.3  39.5  ...  6.8  3.8  15.2  19.6  108.0
8    9.0         Toronto Raptors*  78  242.2  40.2  ...  7.7  4.5  15.1  20.6  108.4
9   10.0         Dallas Mavericks  77  241.0  40.9  ...  7.9  4.6  13.1  23.4  109.9
10  11.0         Milwaukee Bucks*  78  241.3  40.3  ...  6.9  4.9  13.4  20.0  108.6
11  12.0  Portland Trail Blazers*  77  242.3  41.1  ...  7.3  5.1  12.4  20.8  110.5
12  13.0         Houston Rockets*  78  241.9  40.4  ...  7.4  4.6  15.0  20.1  109.3
13  14.0   Golden State Warriors*  77  241.6  40.3  ...  7.6  3.7  13.5  19.8  111.4
14  15.0       San Antonio Spurs*  78  241.6  41.6  ...  7.2  4.1  12.2  19.7  110.4
15  16.0      Philadelphia 76ers*  77  241.6  41.5  ...  7.9  4.0  12.9  22.3  112.2
16  17.0        Charlotte Hornets  77  241.9  42.0  ...  7.1  6.1  13.6  20.6  112.2
17  18.0   Oklahoma City Thunder*  78  242.2  40.8  ...  8.2  5.1  16.9  22.6  110.8
18  19.0            Brooklyn Nets  78  243.8  42.2  ...  7.8  5.4  13.5  22.3  112.5
19  20.0   Minnesota Timberwolves  77  241.9  42.0  ...  6.6  5.6  14.7  22.0  114.0
20  21.0          New York Knicks  77  241.3  42.0  ...  7.4  5.7  13.4  21.0  114.1
21  22.0            Chicago Bulls  78  242.9  42.1  ...  7.5  5.6  13.5  18.9  113.4
22  23.0    Los Angeles Clippers*  78  241.6  41.4  ...  8.2  5.9  13.1  24.0  113.4
23  24.0       Los Angeles Lakers  78  241.3  42.1  ...  8.3  5.1  14.3  21.0  113.7
24  25.0      Cleveland Cavaliers  78  241.0  43.0  ...  6.9  5.6  12.5  19.6  113.9
25  26.0         Sacramento Kings  78  240.6  41.9  ...  7.7  5.1  15.9  21.6  114.9
26  27.0             Phoenix Suns  78  242.2  42.2  ...  9.1  5.0  15.6  20.7  116.3
27  28.0     New Orleans Pelicans  78  240.6  43.2  ...  8.4  5.4  13.8  21.3  116.5
28  29.0       Washington Wizards  78  243.2  43.3  ...  7.8  4.6  15.9  21.4  116.9
29  30.0            Atlanta Hawks  78  242.2  42.6  ...  9.9  5.4  15.1  22.0  118.8
30   NaN           League Average  78  241.7  41.0  ...  7.7  5.0  14.2  21.0  111.1

[31 rows x 25 columns]
```

Comment: glad I could help. I love playing with sports data, scraping sports data. It was actually a major part of my master's degree dissertation.